# Event ID in wrong row, cannot call method deleteEvent

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a spreadsheet for my department to create, edit, and delete work assignments to a google calendar. It's been quite a while since I did any actual coding, so I've been doing a lot of trial and error and referring to the Google App Script and Calendar references. I've finally gotten to the point where I can create the events; however, when I am testing my function to delete events, I've discovered that the event on row two, deletes the event on row three, and when I try to delete the event on row three, I get a "cannot call method deleteEvent" error. I've tried looking through various sites for similar situations and have not been successful. Any help walking me through the error in my code issue would be greatly appreciated. I'm also attempting to attach a link for a video of the spreadsheet as the script is running [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P2y_Jn8s3dO9IK9cdSJEcbh7wfmoOan9/view?usp=sharing)

```
// Adds the custom menu to the active spreadsheet.
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [
    {
      name: "Create New Events",
      functionName: "createCalEvent"
    }, {
      name: "Update Existing Events",
      functionName: "updateCalEvent"
    }, {
      name: "Delete Existing Events",
      functionName: "deleteCalEvent"
    }
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Calendar Options', menuEntries);
}
// Event Status --> Assist in Triggering Update/Delete Functions
var delConfirmed = 'Event Created';
var updateConfirmed = 'Event Updated';
var eventCreate = 'Event Deleted';
function createCalEvent(){
  var calSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = calSheet.getRange('$A2:$J');
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var calDate = row[1]; // COL A
    var calTitle = row[5]; // COL F
    var calGuests = row[6]; // COL G
    var calEType = row[7]; // COL H
    var calID = row[8]; // COL I
    var calStatus = row[9]; // COL J
// If there is a date and both the Event Type (Adjust/Delete) and Status are blank then Create the Calendar Event
    if(calDate !=='' && calEType == '' && calStatus == ''){
    var calEvent = CalendarApp
    .getCalendarById('envysion.com_kmfeb8mqmlv4j9k34l37q7fv3k@group.calendar.google.com')
    .createAllDayEvent(calTitle, new Date(calDate),{guests:calGuests});
      // Update the Status Column
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+2, 10).setValue('Event Created');
    var newEvent = calEvent.getId();
      // Add the Event ID to the Event ID Column
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+2,9).setValue(newEvent);

    Logger.log('Event ID: ' + newEvent + ' Title: ' + calEvent.getTitle() + 'Guests: ' + calEvent.getGuestList());
    }
  }
}
function deleteCalEvent()
{
  // Get range of dates to delete
  var fromDate = new Date(2019,3,1);
  var toDate = new Date(2019,4,1);
// Get Calendar Events
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('envysion.com_kmfeb8mqmlv4j9k34l37q7fv3k@group.calendar.google.com')
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
// Get Spreadsheet Details
  var calSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = calSheet.getRange('$A2:$J');
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var calDate = row[1];
    var calTitle = row[5];
    var calGuests = row[6];
    var calEType = row[7];
    var calID = row[8];
    var calStatus = row[9];
// Check if the Type column is set to Delete and if the event hasn't already been deleted
    if(calEType == 'Delete' && calStatus !== 'Event Deleted'){
      events[i].deleteEvent();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+2, 10).setValue('Event Deleted');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+2, 9).setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and provide [mcve]. And if you receive an answer that helps you to resolve your problem please check it off so that everyone can see that the problem is resolved. Generally, we like to see the code that you have are having a problem with and a description of what you have tried. If you successfully integrate all of these suggestions into your question then your much more likely to get a quick resolution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need do something like this

```
if(calEType == 'Delete' && calStatus !== 'Event Deleted'){
  var _event_ = calendar.getEventById(calStatus);
  if(_event_){
    _event_.deleteEvent();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+2, 10).setValue('Event Deleted');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+2, 9).setValue('');
  }
}
```

This is because you may have a different number of events in the calendar and in the sheet.

Comment: Thank you @oshliaer! var _event_ and the additional if statement stopped the errors; however it was only updating the spreadsheet and not the calendar itself. I swapped calStatus with calID and it successfully updated both the sheet and calendar and no error messages. Appreciate the update with reasoning!